# I want to ask in the if statement if the cake is baked how do I do that in single-dimensional array? I'm stuck

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio

```
using System;

namespace ConsoleApp12
{
    class Cake
    {
        private string cakeType;
        private int weight;
        private bool baked;

        public Cake(string cakeType, int weight)
        {
            this.cakeType = cakeType;
            this.weight = weight;
            this.baked = true;
        }
        public Cake(string cakeType, int weight, bool baked)
        {
            this.cakeType = cakeType;
            this.weight = weight;
            this.baked = baked;
        }
        public Cake(int weight)
        {
            this.cakeType = "chocolate";
            this.weight = weight;
            this.baked = true;
        }

        public string IsBaked()
        {
            int count = 0;
            Cake[] CakeArr = new Cake[3];
            for (int i = 0; i < CakeArr.Length; i++)
            {
                if (/* if cake is baked */)
                {
                    return "The Cake is indeed baked...";
                }
                else
                {
                    count++;
                }
            }
            return "There are: " + count + " not baked cakes...";
        }
        public string GetCakeType() { return this.cakeType; }
        public int GetWeight() { return this.weight; }
        public bool GetBaked() { return this.baked; }
        public void SetBaked(bool baked) { this.baked = baked; }

        public void Sold(int weight) { this.weight -= weight; }
    }
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Cake c1 = new Cake(1800);
            Cake c2 = new Cake("cheese", 1200, false);
            Cake c3 = new Cake("chocolate", 2100, true);

            c1.Sold(400);

            if (c1 == c3)
                Console.WriteLine("aaa");
            else
                Console.WriteLine("bbb");

            c3.Sold(700);

            if (c1 == c2 || c2 == c3)
                Console.WriteLine("ccc");
            else
                if (c1 == c3)
                Console.WriteLine("ddd");

            c1.Sold(1400);
            c2.SetBaked(c1.GetBaked());
            if (c2.GetBaked())
                Console.WriteLine("eee");

            Console.WriteLine(c2.IsBaked());
        }
    }
}
```

I did everything I need but I do not know how to make the system check if the cake is baked in an if statement...
It doesnt matter what everything else do like the other methods because they all supposed to work anyways I just need to find a solution to the method IsBaked in the class Cake.
Please help, thank you.

Comment: c1, c2 and c3 are never equal - they are always separate instances

Comment: In that IsBaked you are creating an array, but never add values to it. I assume you want to fill it with c1 etc?

Comment: If you find the solution, you could click '✔' to mark it as an answer to change its status to Answered. It will also help others to solve a similar issue. See also [stackoverflow.com/help/why-vote](https://stackoverflow.com/help/why-vote)

Answer (score 3):

Assuming you want to check how many of `c1, c2, c3` are baked, you might want to create an extension method:

```
public static class MyCakeExtensionMethods{

    public static string HowManyAreNotBaked(this Cake[] cakeArr ){
            int count = 0;
            for (int i = 0; i < cakeArr.Length; i++)
            {
                if (!cakeArr[i].GetBaked())
                {
                     count++;
                }
            }
            if( count == 0){
              return "all cakes are baked";

            return "There are: " + count + " not baked cakes...";
    }
}
```

Note that the body could be mostly simplified to `CakeArr.Count(c => c.GetBaked());`

But there are other issues with your code:

- You should probably be using [properties](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/properties) instead of get/set methods
- You should probably not allow the cake type to be changed after creation. Unless you found some way to transform a cheese-cake into a chocolatecake in the real world.
- You should probably change `SetBaked(bool baked)` into `Bake()`, since you cannot un-bake a cake.
- You should probably add a check to `Sold` to ensure you cannot sell more cake than there is.

Comment: The logic in this method seems flawed, as you'll say "all cakes are baked" when there is one or more unbaked cake. I guess `count > 0` should be `count == 0`. Also the method is called "HowManyAreBaked" and you seem to answer "HowManyAreNotBaked"

Comment: Additionally, `if` should be `if (!cakeArr[i].GetBaked())` (with array access `[i]`), and I'm not really sure you can use `Sum` with `bool`, so you might need to use something like `CakeArr.Sum(c => c.GetBaked() ? 1 : 0);` if you want to go with the Linq simplification :)